# enter key and multiple submit buttons in .net

Tags: asp.net, forms, button

if i have multiple submit buttons and the user enters some text in a textbox and presses enter. How can i specify which button event i want to fire?

Answer (score 13):

You can specify for an asp.net Panel the id of button in the property `DefaultButton`. So, you need to group the controls into panels and then you can specify the default button for any of them. Also, you can specify a default button for the whole page - in the form tag.

Comment: And what would be the result in HTML ?